# How to write a stored procedure whose input parameter is a selection from a drop down list & pass the result into a blank text box?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, drop-down-menu

Here is my procedure, which I have executed in SQL Management studio successfully but I can't get it to run in visual studio. When I run it in visual studio it won't let me select the input parameter so I want to run it where the input parameter is whatever the user selects from a drop down in the application.

Here is the procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLastCustomerID_CustomerTypeSelect]
(@CustomerType varchar(20)= Null) 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
--@CustomerType varchar = 'Norcross' 

 AS
 BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
Select case @CustomerType
When 'Norcross'
Then (SELECT  MAX(custnum)
from TSarCustomer 
where dbo.ParseAlphaChars(CustNum) between 25000 and 79999 and OpenedDate >      
dateadd(d,-120,GETDATE()))
When 'Gaffey'
Then(SELECT  MAX(custnum)
from TSarCustomer
where (dbo.ParseAlphaChars(CustNum) between 80000 and 150000) and OpenedDate    > dateadd(d,-120,GETDATE()))
When 'CranePro'
then (SELECT  MAX(dbo.ParseAlphaChars(CustNum))
from TSarCustomer
where CustNum like '%K' and OpenedDate > '1/1/2012')
When 'CranePro'
then(SELECT  MAX(dbo.ParseAlphaChars(CustNum))
from TSarCustomer
where CustNum like '%C' and OpenedDate > '1/1/2005')
When 'Internet'
Then (SELECT  MAX(dbo.ParseAlphaChars(CustNum))
from TSarCustomer
where CustNum like '%W' and OpenedDate > '1/1/2012')
When 'M'
Then (SELECT  MAX(dbo.ParseAlphaChars(CustNum))
from TSarCustomer
where CustNum like '%M' and OpenedDate > '1/1/2012')
end

end
```

Here is my Drop-down code, the choices for this drop-down are being pulled from a table.

```
       <tr>
        <td class="auto-style3">Customer Type:</td>
        <td colspan="1" class="auto-style4">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListCustomerType" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCustomerType" DataTextField="CustomerType" DataValueField="CustomerType" Height="22px" Width="113px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceCustomerType" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AceWOMConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CustomeryType]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style3" >
            Assign Take-Stock#:</td>
        <td class="auto-style3"> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="TSCustomerNumber" runat="server">
```

```
            </asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

So I need helping figuring out how to run the stored procedure when the user chooses a drop-down, take the selection from the drop-down, pass it to the stored procedure as the input parameter and than post the result from the procedure into the empty text box marked by ID "TSCustomerNumber"

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This does not strike me as a very useful question for the broader community, because it's too specific; it's a combination of four simpler problems. Ideally, you would look at each issue separately and ask questions where necessary; for example: **1.** "How do I get the selected value from an ASP.NET DropDownList?" **2.** "How do I invoke a stored procedure from .NET and pass arguments to it?", **3.** "How do I retrieve the result from a stored procedure in .NET code?", and **4.** "How do I update an ASP.NET TextBox?" Each of these questions is likely to already have an answer here on SO.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, I am new to programming and to SO so I apologize if my format was unconventional. You are right that if its broken down into sub questions that these have been covered already and I have actually read the multiple answers and responses for those smaller question but I guess my programming experience is so noob that I couldn't make it work so I figured I would ask for my specific case.

Comment: No harm done. I just wanted to point out that problems are often easily solved if broken down into smaller problems. I hope you'll find here what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the onselectedindexchanged event handler on your dropdownlist.

```
onselectedindexchanged="itemSelected"
```

then create a method in your code behind that handles the event and gets the dropdownlist value as a parameter , calls SP passing in parameter, updating the textbox when it's done:

```
protected void itemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var val = DropDownListCustomerType.SelectedItem.Value;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myDataConnection)) {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetLastCustomerID_CustomerTypeSelect", con)) {
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = val;

     con.Open();
     TSCustomerNumber.Text = (String) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   }
  }
}
```

That should at least get you close...

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! So I am trying your solution and your logic definitely makes sense but for some reason my cs file is telling me that:  The name 'DropDownListCustomerType' doesn't not exist in the current context. Do I need to add some sort of using statement or reference?

Comment: you need to add name="" attributes to the dropdown and textbox so you can reference it from code.

Comment: Got it working using all your tips, required a little more manuevering but you definitely got me just about there voidzero. Should anyone come across this in the future just message me and I can at least compare it to my final code.

Answer (score -1):

```
            string query = "select Fechacumplimiento from TTareasIngreso where descripcion='" + dprTarea.Text + "' and descripcion='" + lblagencia.Text + "' ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {

                TxtFechaPago.Text = dr["Fechacumplimiento"].ToString();


            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider adding some explanations to your code example, even if the solution appears trivial to you. See also [answer]. Thanks!

Comment: Lo solucionaste amigo ?